# Firewall trouble when deploying Tomcat at CentOS

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, tomcat

I am trying to deploy a Tomcat server in a CentOS environment, but it is not receiving requests.

Executing startup.sh works properly and the logs show that tomcat is running

```
16-Dec-2016 13:36:58.440 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
16-Dec-2016 13:36:58.444 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
16-Dec-2016 13:36:58.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 14803 ms
```

When running netstat to check listening ports, it is shown as listening

```
$netstat -atnp|grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3321/java
```

In order to skip the firewall, I added a custom rule at iptables.

```
$iptables -nL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50060
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50030
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50105
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50090
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50075
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:50070
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:123
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I added the rule on top in order to avoid the mistake of adding it after the general reject. Iptables is active as service returns the following:

```
$service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptables.service
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-12-16 13:09:47 EST; 1h 45min ago
Main PID: 728 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service
```

However, request are not reaching Tomcat, as the localhost access logs are empty.

Firewalld is not interferring with the connection because it claims to be disabled:

```
$firewall-cmd --state
not running
```

Is there other firewall settings that I am missing?

Comment: What version of CentOS? What happens if you run service iptables status?

Comment: I added the rest of iptables rules. Mi version is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core). Calling service iptables status shows iptables as active.

Comment: Did you tried to disable firewall? Do this so you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: OK, so the firewall port is open and the service is listening. But what happens when you try to connect to it?

Answer (score 10):

I think what is going on here is you are mixing your technologies.

Try:

service iptables stop

See you still get the same response

If you do then you need to remove either iptables or firewalld